# Save third-party object in ORM

Tags: java, android, orm, android-sqlite, kotlin

I'm taking objects from REST api and work with this objects using a third-party library (contains the object data and methods for work with these). I needed save objects using an ORM (many objects to manage), but can't add annotations for use in any ORM. Can extends object, but I can't use a other class with same fields.

How do persist objects in sqlite without annotation in android? I'ts possible extends object and override fields for add annotations?

I'm develop with kotlin and java in same project.

Comment: Have your tried that?

Comment: Yes, with GreenDAO and DBFlow, but I can't use for save objects

Comment: You may try JDXA ORM for Android. It does not require annotations or inheritance from a base class for model classes.